# Google Analytics Goal Not Recording Accurately

Tags: google-analytics

I'm not getting the right results returned for a goal I have set up. The goal says the last 7 days have 92 goal conversions, when it should be 400+.

When a user completes a subscription purchase, they land on a confirmation page. We have several subdomains that the user can be coming from as well as the potential for a reference appended to the URL. So, I have the goal set up as a regular expression like this:

> .*/insider/confirm.*

If, for example, the user pays and then is directed to the following page, shouldn't the goal be recorded?

> test.com/insider/confirm?ref=2343

Answer (score 0):

As I can't see anything wrong with the regular expression, although very greedy, the goals should be captured with the above example URL and goal setup.

Have you recently set this goal up? A thing with goals are that they aren't historically applicable to your data. They start collecting data from the point where you set it up.

Have you tried using the above regexp in the "All pages"-report under "Behavior"? Enter it into the filter pattern and there you can see exactly what pages your regexp would capture.

Comment: On All Pages I get that for the last week we have 767 pageviews (681 unique) on the /insider/confirm page. I set up this goal over a week ago and it says 137 for the past week. Any idea?